# a word for in between two

Tags: single-word-requests

something like dawn, twilight, purgatory

Comment: in between two worlds, that is

Comment: [Interplanetary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space#Interplanetary_space)?

Answer (score 1):

"liminal" is a good word for this, and is usually used in contexts describing the boundary between the "real" world and some fantasy world

"The alleyway behind Denny's feels incredibly liminal... it's almost like there's a portal to a different dimension there"